# apache hadoop-tools installation in cloudera

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, hadoop-plugins

I have cloudera 5.14 development environment. I want to install apache *hadoop-tools*([link](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/a55d6bba71c81c1c4e9d8cd11f55c78f10a548b0/hadoop-tools)) in the cloudera distribution .
Specifically  I need *`hadoop-resourceestimator`* ([link](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/a55d6bba71c81c1c4e9d8cd11f55c78f10a548b0/hadoop-tools/hadoop-resourceestimator)).

There is no documentation available how to install the same .

Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK cdh5.14.x is based on old hadoop version 2.6.0 which does not have resourceestimator tool.

Comment: @mazaneicha can it be possible to install just the tool in 2.6.0 ?

Comment: I don't think so but don't mind to be proved wrong.

Comment: Based on https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/release-notes/topics/rg_cdh_620_unsupported_features.html @mazaneicha, is right.  If the resource estimator is not supported in CDH6.x I doubt it would be in CDH5.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK cdh5.14.x is based on the old hadoop version 2.6.0 which does not have resourceestimator tool.
It is available but is not supported in CDH6 ("not supported" is not the same as "not available"). You can find resourceestimator in CDH6.x distribution,

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   71105 Dec  6 03:13 /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/hadoop-resourceestimator-3.0.0-cdh6.0.x-SNAPSHOT.jar`

and you're free to use it, but Cloudera Support won't provide any help.